# Improving SVG triangles animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, canvas, svg

I made a script to draw and animate polygons:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZRxRV

Actually I addeda few polygons (i want to add over 50).

But I want to animate my figure like this (slow width and height transform):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVYWJQ

How to implement similar animation to my triangle figure ?

```
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
    var polyElems = [], numSteps = -660, stepNum = 0;
    /*var pts = [[451.1,386.7], [93.5,194], [343.4,-7.1]];*/
    var pts = [[-5.1,-7.1], [343.4,-7.1], [386.7,194],
              [451.1,93.5], [386.7,194], [343.4,-7.1],
              [-5.1,-7.1], [262.3,183.5], [386.7,194],
    ];

    // var palette = [['#ff0000'], ['#000']];
    var palette = ['#49c9d5','#02abc8','#02abc8','#430017'];

    var polyPts = [[0,1,2],[3,2,1],[0,7,2]];

    for (var x = 0; x < polyPts.length; x++) {
      polyElems[x] = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, 'polygon');
      polyElems[x].setAttribute('fill', [palette[x]]);
        // polyElems[x].setAttribute('fill', '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
        // random hex color routine from http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/
      drawPolygon(x);
    }

    function anim() {
      pts = pts.map(function(pt) {
        return pt.map(function(coord) {
          return coord + 1 * (Math.random() - 0.5); // move each point
        });
      });
      for (var x = 0; x < polyPts.length; x++) {drawPolygon(x);}
      stepNum += 5;
      /*if (stepNum < numSteps) */requestAnimationFrame(anim); // redo anim'n until all anim'n steps don
    }

    window.setInterval(anim(), 1);
    //anim(); // start the animation

    function drawPolygon(x) {
      var ptNums = polyPts[x];
      var currCoords = [pts[ptNums[0]], pts[ptNums[1]], pts[ptNums[2]]].join();
        // creates a string of coordinates; note that [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]].join() yields "1,2,3,4,5,6"
      polyElems[x].setAttribute('points', currCoords);
      svg.appendChild(polyElems[x]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're wanting to animate a "wobble" to your Delaunay-styled triangles.

**Problem**

Any one triangle might share a vertex with quite a few other triangles.

Suppose TriangleA & TriangleB share a common vertex.

You can't just "wobble" triangleA's vertex because that would cause TriangleA and TriangleB to become separated at that common vertex.

**Solution**

For each commonly shared vertex, you must instruct each polygon with that same vertex to move their common vertex to the exact same new "wobble" point.

**Here's one way to do that (*warning*: pseudo-code follows!):**

1. Create your polygons (add 50 more if desired):
2. Create an array containing every polygon's vertices (polygon==triangle). So every polygon's point[0], point[1] & point[2] goes into one vertices array.

   ```
   var vertices=[];

   vertices.push({ poly:poly1, x:poly1.point[0].x, y:poly1.point[0].y, index:0 });
   vertices.push({ poly:poly1, x:poly1.point[1].x, y:poly1.point[1].y, index:1 });
   vertices.push({ poly:poly1, x:poly1.point[2].x, y:poly1.point[2].y, index:2 });

   ... and same for each poly#
   ```
3. To "wobble", iterate through the vertex-array and change each common vertex by a wobble-factor. For example, you might find 3 triangles that share the common vertex of `[x==5 / y==10]`. To wobble, you might tell each of the 3 triangles to change that common vertex to `[x==7 / y==9]`. For a smoother looking animation you might animation the movement from [5,10] to [7,9] over a period of frames.

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var points=[[-5.1,-7.1], [343.4,-7.1], [386.7,194],
            [451.1,93.5], [386.7,194], [343.4,-7.1],
            [-5.1,-7.1], [262.3,183.5], [386.7,194]
           ];

var vertices=[];
var vpoints=[];
var tris=[];
var colors=['skyblue','salmon','lightgreen'];
var wobbles=[{x:0,y:0},{x:0,y:0},{x:0,y:0}];

for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){
  // make pt easier to match
  pt={
    x:Math.round(points[i][0]),
    y:Math.round(points[i][1])
  }
  var vindex=-1;
  for(var k=0;k<vertices.length;k++){
    var vp=vertices[k].point;
    if(vp.x==pt.x && vp.y==pt.y){ vindex=k; break; }
  }
  if(vindex<0){
    vertices.push({ point:pt });
    vindex=vertices.length-1;
  }
  vpoints.push(vindex);
}

for(var i=0;i<points.length;i+=3){
  var id=parseInt(i/3);
  var tri={
    id:id,
    color:colors[id],
    points:[vpoints[i+0],vpoints[i+1],vpoints[i+2]],
    draw:function(){
      var pt0=vertices[this.points[0]].point;
      var pt1=vertices[this.points[1]].point;
      var pt2=vertices[this.points[2]].point;
      var w0=vertices[this.points[0]].wobble;
      var w1=vertices[this.points[1]].wobble;
      var w2=vertices[this.points[2]].wobble;
      var dx,dy;
      var pct=animatePct/100;
      dx=pt0.x-w0.x;
      dy=pt0.y-w0.y;
      var p0={x:pt0.x-w0.x*pct,y:pt0.y-w0.y*pct};
      dx=pt1.x-w0.x;
      dy=pt1.y-w0.y;
      var p1={x:pt1.x-w1.x*pct,y:pt1.y-w1.y*pct};
      dx=pt2.x-w0.x;
      dy=pt2.y-w0.y;
      var p2={x:pt2.x-w2.x*pct,y:pt2.y-w2.y*pct};
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(p0.x,p0.y);
      ctx.lineTo(p1.x,p1.y);
      ctx.lineTo(p2.x,p2.y);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle=this.color;
      ctx.fill();
    },
  };
  tris.push(tri);
}

var nextTime=0;
var delay=1000/60*3;
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
var animatePct;
var animateRate=5;
var wobbleDirection=1;
buildWobble();

function animate(time){
  if(time<nextTime){requestAnimationFrame(animate);return;}
  nextTime=time+delay;
  drawAll();
  animatePct+=animateRate;
  if(animatePct>100){  animateRate*=-1; animatePct=100; }
  if(animatePct<000){  animateRate*=-1; animatePct=0; }
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);    
}

function drawAll(){
  // draw
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.translate(25,25);
  for(var i=0;i<tris.length;i++){
    tris[i].draw();
  }
  ctx.translate(-25,-25);
}

function buildWobble(){
  animatePct=0;
  for(var i=0;i<vertices.length;i++){
    vertices[i].wobble={x:Math.random()*40-20,y:Math.random()*40-20};
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=510 height=260></canvas>
```

Comment: I've added an efficient "wobble" example starting with your `points` array and drawing wobbling triangles on an html5 canvas. Cheers!

Comment: That sounds good! But how to make  triangle move more slowly and smoothly? When I increase "delay", animation is not smoothly :( I want to add "transition" effect to triangle motion.

Comment: In animation "smooth" implies smaller movements with less delay. You can also make the eye perceive smoother motion by moving your vertex linearly from one offset to another offset rather than random wobbling. This works because the eye is good at perceiving a linear path and using the mind to "interpolate" motion along the perceived path.

Comment: Hmm it is posibble in your "canvas version code" ? What can I change ? It is very important for me but I don't have enought knowledge in animations :(

Comment: @Dominik I've (again!) updated my answer to show how to do a smoother  animation. The updated answer uses linear interpolation to move each vertex to a new position. This lets the eye perceive a smoother movement. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you a lot ! Your effort is very important knowledge for me. I learned a lot. I have only one question- can you show me how to add random animation, not repeat?

Comment: Just re-call `buildWobble` after the animation has completed its forward and back cycle. Cheers!

Comment: What did you mean by "re-call" ?

Comment: Hm if I give "buildWobble();" in animate function, my animation crashed